# Change values from the YAxis in a Chart Object C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

Good morning everyone!

I managed to handle a chart object in a Windows Form program made in C#. I have now a problem: I want to control the YAxis scale displayed in my chart. I have to make a chart with the amount of time used and I want to represent the YAxis scale with the format hh:mm:ss. Is it possible to do it? How can I accomplish this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT 1**: This is the code with which I construct my chart:

```
for (m = 0; m < mySeriesValues.Length; m++)
 {
     for (i = myFields.Count + 1; i < myAux.Columns.Count; i++)
     {
         Series mySerie = new Series();
         CustomLabel myItemLabel = new CustomLabel();

         mySerie.Name = mySeriesValues[m] + " - " + myAux.Columns[i].ColumnName;
         mySerie.XValueMember = myAux.Columns[0].ColumnName;
         mySerie.YValueMembers = myAux.Columns[i].ColumnName;
         for (j = 0; j < myAux.Rows.Count; j++)
         {
             nameValue = "";
             for (n = 1; n < myFields.Count + 1; n++) 
             {
                 if (n == 1) { nameValue += myAux.Rows[j][n].ToString(); }
                 else { nameValue += " - " + myAux.Rows[j][n].ToString(); }
             }
             if (mySeriesValues[m].Equals(nameValue))
             {
                 auxStringValue = myAux.Rows[j][i].ToString();
                 auxValue = Convert.ToDecimal(myAux.Rows[j][i].ToString());
                 resultTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)auxValue);
                 myLabel = String.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s", resultTime.Hours, resultTime.Minutes, resultTime.Seconds);
                 myItemLabel.Text = myLabel;
                 mySerie.Points.Add((double)auxValue).Label = myLabel;
                 this.chartReport.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Tag = myLabel;
             }
         }
         this.chartReport.Series.Add(mySerie);
         this.chartReport.Series[m]["PointWidth"] = "1";
     }
 }
```

**EDIT 2**: I obtained almost what I need. I made used of this sentence:

```
this.chartReport.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = String.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s", resultTime.Hours, resultTime.Minutes, resultTime.Seconds);
```

However, what it does is a mask over the values of my seconds, so if I have 500000 seconds, they're converted to 50:00:00, and I need to convert the seconds to hours/minutes/seconds but I can't get the values of the YAxis scale...

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Show us some code, please.

Comment: I can show code, but it's the way I make the chart, and it was a bit rude to rest value of my question directly without first asking for the code...

Comment: @RuiJarimba There is the code you asked for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question and it was in a VB forum apart from this one:

It is possible to customize your scale with the function `AxisY.CustomLabels`. I saw an example on [this website](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?688353-RESOLVED-MSChart-trying-to-use-total-time-as-YAxis) and I adapted it to C# in the following sentence:

```
double valueMinimum = this.chartReport.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum; 
double valueMaximum = this.chartReport.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum; 
double labelInterval = this.chartReport.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval;

for (double increment = valueMinimum; increment <= valueMaximum; increment += labelInterval)
            {
                TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(increment);
                chartReport.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(
                    increment - labelInterval / 2, 
                    increment + labelInterval / 2, String.Format ("{0}h:{1}m:{2}s",
                    ts.Days * 24 + ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds)
                    );
            }
```

With this code, I still can introduce the seconds as a value to my series and not the time, and also I solve the fact that if the time is bigger than a day, I can show the days or the hours.